# Как разбить таблицу стилей на части?

Tags: css

Посоветуйте, как лучше всего разбивать стили на файлы, чтобы не получалась огромная колбаса из стилей? Какие есть варианты, технологии? Какие у них плюсы/минусы?

Comment: Чтобы не получалась огромная колбаса из стилей, нужно не создавать эту колбасу :)

Comment: Их с самого начала разбивают на определенные разделы: один для каркаса например, другой для слайдера, третий для новостей. А уже перед релизом файлы стилей объединяют в один.

Comment: Какие технологии? Какие плюсы/минусы? Открыл css в блокноте, вырезал кусок, вставил в новый файл! Лень открывать в блокноте - напиши простенький парсер, который будет разбивать один css-файл на несколько так, чтобы не разрывать на части определение одного правила.

Comment: я не знаю даже с чего начать, думал, не придется писать очевидные вещи, но скептицизм очень свойственен программистам, да и айтишникам вообще.

>> взять да разбить
взял, да разбил. получилось пятнадцать @import. я так понимаю, это 15 ненужных запросов к серверу? то же самое, если встраивать с помощью link.

>> Чтобы не получалась огромная колбаса из стилей, нужно не создавать эту колбасу :)
в натуре! как же я сразу не догадался просто не писать ничего в css файле! ой... а что это сайт у меня черно-белый стал?

Comment: >>Их с самого начала разбивают на определенные разделы: один для каркаса например, другой для слайдера, третий для новостей. А уже перед релизом файлы стилей объединяют в один.


хотелось бы, чтобы они собирались сами в один. и не перед релизом, а во время. автоматически обновлялись при изменении и т.д. самому писать кеширование или есть уже что-нибудь готовое? или можно как-то вообще обойтись без него, как такового?

Comment: Чтобы сами собирались в один - это запросто. Просто при сохранении дебужной версии из редактора герится релизный CSS. Правил при этом можно насоздавать сколько угодно, хоть на каждую страницу. Ну или ещё как-то, вариантов подобной автоматизации навалом, как хочешь так и делай.

Про "не создавать колбасу" что удивило? К CSS нужно относиться как к любому другому коду. Чтобы и через полгода ты мог ткнуться в любое место и сказать зачем оно. В иной css посмотришь: каждая пыркалка со своим id тащит полстраницы свойств, а что это - непонятно. А сократить можно было бы раз в 5 (см. первую "C").

Comment: попробуйте [stylus](http://learnboost.github.io/stylus/), или [less](http://lesscss.ru/) stylus [используется в яндексе](http://habrahabr.ru/company/yandex/blog/169415/)

Answer (score 3):

Лучше всего по области использования. То есть стремиться к тому, чтобы к странице подключалось только то, что необходимо. Это недостижимый результат на больших проектах.

пример:

reset.css - файл обнуления. Подключается везде.
basic.css - файл общих для всех страниц стилей.

catalog.css - каталог
modal.css - модальные окна
acp.css - админпанель

по технологиям: firebug или аналоги. просто смотрите что где используется, записываете. Можно попытаться автоматизировать. Некоторые IDEшки сами умеют определять неиспользуемые стили.

Comment: @knes а есть практика их компилирования для отдельных страниц? несколько таблиц стилей постоянно используются на многих страницах, но не на всех. и именно для этих страниц собрать css в котором есть всё необходимое. стоит так делать? я, конечно, понимаю, что тут нужно смотреть по ситуации. но мало ли, есть какое-либо дельное замечание.

Comment: Есть. Чем меньше отдельных файлов, тем лучше.

    if(!file_exists(compiled_page1.css)){
      //запихиваем все данные в один файл.
    }
    print('<link rel="stylesheet" href="compiled_page1.css" />');

Answer (score 0):

[Multilayer CSS](http://operatino.github.io/MCSS/en/) - отличная методология